# How to find maximum value in a file?

Tags: python, file, max

My program should open and read through the file specified. It needs to return the maximum value in the file.  This is what I have, I figured I would get this error but I'm not sure how to fix it! The second to last line is the problem. `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`.

```
def maxValueInFile(fileName):
    iterator = iter(fileName)
    minim, maxim = sorted((next(iterator), next(iterator)))

    for item in iterator:
        if item < minim:
            minim = item
        elif item > maxim:
            maxim = item
    return (maxim)

with open('fileName.txt','r') as f:
    values=(float(value_str) for line in f for value_str in line.split())
    minim, maxim = maxValueInFile(values)
print (minum, maxim)
```

Comment: What's wrong with the `min` and `max` functions...?

Comment: @ssdecontrol Probably not allowed to use it due to homework restrictions.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: The argument you're passing `maxValueInFile()` isn't a file name.

Comment: you need to return both minim and maxim `return minim, maxim`

Comment: @martineau what should it be?

Comment: You could just call it `values` or `float_values` in the function. Might want to change the name of the function to something else, too, like `find_max_value()`. There's also no point in sorting them first (or just sort them and take the last one in the result).

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do. The title of your question says you want the maximum value, but your code looks like it's trying to find and return both the minimum _and_ maximum.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want (or can) use the built-in functions, you can simply iterate over the lines of the file, something like this:

```
with open('fileName.txt','r') as f:
    minim, maxim = float('inf'), float('-inf')
    for line in f:
        next_item = float(line)
        if next_item < minim:
            minim = next_item
        elif next_item > maxim:
            maxim = next_item
    print(minim, maxim)
```

This code is faster than yours, because it does not sort the values in your iterator.

Your code isn't working because of returning wrong number results:

```
minim, maxim = maxValueInFile(values)
```

and compare with

```
return (maxim)
```

You simply should remove bracers and `minim` variable:

```
maxim = maxValueInFile(values)
```

and

```
return (maxim)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, please refer to the @ShadyAtef answer to read the docs, they are extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

The statement 'return (maxim)' returns the maximum value as float and not tuple.

`minim, maxim = maxValueInFile(values)` tries to unpack the return value into these variable and this means the right hand side must be iteratable.

you can change it to

```
maxim = maxValueInFile(values)
```

---

You can read more about unpacking operators in [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `minim, maxim = maxValueInFile(values)`.  Here you expect that the function return a tuple with 2 values (or other iterable object).

The solution is simple, either change it to `maxim = maxValueInFile(values)` or in the function change the return value to `return minim, maxim`.

In the first case you should use the build in `max` but if you are not allowed, then inside the function there is no need to also calculate the minimum value.

In second case, then change the name of the function to something that better reflects the objective of the function, such as `minmax`.

Answer (score 0):

If you *do* want to use python's stdlib, this does it

```
with open('fileName.txt') as fp:
    floats = map(float, fp)
print("maximum", max(floats))
print("minimum", min(floats))
```

Comment: this will fail to find the minimum in python 3 because map is generator